# php- How to record which user clicked on a link to download a file

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to record which user has downloaded a file in an SQL database. Every file uploaded has its path displayed as a link on the site, allowing the user to download that file from a folder on the server. I am having trouble figuring out how to record which user has downloaded a file though. How can I query my database that a specific user has clicked a specific link? I have the user id stored as a session variable, so possessing the user id is not a problem. My code to display the downloadable files are as follows:

```
<?php
      session_start();

        $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "project_website1";
            $user_id = $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ];

        // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "SELECT task_id,file, description, title, deadline_claim FROM task";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<table><tr><th>TITLE</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th><th>DEADLINE</th><th>TASK</th></tr>";
                // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //echo "<tr><td>" . $row["file"]. "</td><td>" . $row["title"]. "</td><td>" . $row["deadline_claim"]. "</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td><td>".$row["deadline_claim"]."<td><a href='" .$row["file"]. "'>CLAIM</td></a>";



                }
                    echo "</table>";
            } else {
                    echo "0 results";
        }

            $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you may add a table `downloaded_by` and `add userID / fileID` and everytime the link is clicked/file DL ? you have file ID, user ID in session (I would personnaly use ajax to call a script), then, if he already had accessed that file -> +1 or denied

Comment: Maybe the link that contains the file the user is trying to download have a php that just saves the user id in a field of the database.

Comment: Yes I have a table in my database for that already, I just don't know how to query the table when a link has been clicked. I have no experience with java script, but I'm presuming the solution would be something like an onClickListener? Im just wondering if this could be accomplished with php.

Comment: Instead of doing this `<a href='" .$row["file"]. "'>CLAIM</td></a>`, you would do instead `<a href='?file=" .$row["id"]. "'>CLAIM</td></a>` (use the id value). When user clicks the claim, it quiries the db for the file, at that point you record the user and file they downloaded. Ajax not required, but could be used if desired.

Comment: it can be done with javascript , loop a form for each file and onclick set your php action then in javascript function execute php script

Comment: So ?file will be a php script which will insert the id of the download and the id of the user to the downloaded table?

Comment: Yes, doing a `?file=` is using all PHP and the `id` is the id of the file in the table.

Comment: yes , use <form method="get" action="<? php echo $row["file"]; ?>"> <input type="button" name="name" Value"your file name" onClicksetinsertAction(); /></form> if you interested in this method i can post a answer little later

Comment: Hi Gert, if you can provide the solution with the onClick method I would appreciate it, I'm having difficulty with sending the id of the file to another php script to download it and query the downloaded files table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be purely PHP, as suggested, just use the `task_id` of the row in your file table. Here is a basic example, noting I have reorganized some elements to help keep your script cleaner. Ideally you will want to keep the functions on a different page and include them when you want to use them. Keeps your script cleaner and more easily readable.:

```
# Better to make a function/class to do your database so you can reuse it easily.
function getConnection( $servername = "localhost", $username = "root",$password = "",$dbname = "project_website1")
    {
        # Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        # Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        return $conn;
    }

# Make a task retrieval function/class that will deal with getting the rows only
function getTasks($con,$id=false)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT task_id,file, description, title, deadline_claim FROM task";
        # I am assuming your task_id values are numeric, so I don't sanitize here
        if ($id) {
            if(is_numeric($id))
                # Append sql
                $sql .= " WHERE `task_id` = '{$id}'";
            else
                # You shouldn't get this exception unless someone is trying to
                # Manually put something else here via injection attempt
                throw new Exception("Id must be numeric!");
        }

        $result = $con->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $new[] = $row;
            }
        }
        # Send back rows
        return (!empty($new))? $new : array();
    }

# This is more of a listener, but it will cut down on some redundant check-script
function getFileId()
    {
        if(!empty($_GET['file']) && is_numeric($_GET['file']))
            return (!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'download')? $_GET['file'] : false;

        return false;
    }

# As noted, you would include the functions here...
session_start();
# Get session id
$user_id = $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ];
# Get the database connection
$conn    = getConnection();
# If there is a download
if(!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'download') {
    # Get the tasks, could be based on id or all
    $tasks   = getTasks($conn, getFileId());
    # Save to the database, make sure that you either bind parameters, or
    # check that the values are numeric (if they are supposed to be numeric)
    # Also check the count here first for the task before inserting. Make an error if not.
    # Usually means user is trying to manipulate the request
    $conn->query("INSERT into downloads (`fileid`,`userid`) VALUES('".$tasks[0]['task_id']."','".$user_id."')");
    # Download file. If you want to obfuscate the file, you would use
    # download headers instead:
    # http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php
    header('Location: '.$tasks[0]['file']);
    # Stop execution
    exit;
}

# Get all tasks
$tasks   = getTasks($conn);
# If there are rows, output them
if (!empty($tasks)) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>TITLE</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th><th>DEADLINE</th><th>TASK</th></tr>";
    # output data of each row
    foreach($tasks as $row) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td><td>".$row["deadline_claim"]."<td><a href='?action=download&file=" .$row["task_id"]. "'>CLAIM</td></a>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Final note, I have not tested this, so be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works for me, allows the user to download the file and also queries the database table to record which user downloaded what file. Did have to change one thing, I was getting an error with the $tasks variable for use with the claimed_tasks table, saying it was undefined, so I defined it outside of the if statement that checks to see if a download is there or not.

Comment: Oh yeah, I had moved some stuff around after I posted the answer so there was some things I probably missed!

Answer (score 0):

your header for calling script in html

```
<head>
   <script laqnguage="javascript" src="myfunction.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
```

then in your while loop in php jump out of php

```
?>
<form name"myform" method="get" action="<? php echo $row["file"]; ?>"> 
<input type="button" name="name" Value"<? php echo $row["file"]; ?>" onClick="setinsertAction();" />
</form>
```

then jump into php again

```
<?php
```

now create a file called myfunction.js and put this inside

```
function setinsertAction() {
document.myform.action = "HERE PUT YOUR PHP FILE THAT WILL DO THE QUERY";
document.myform.submit()'
}
```

if all goes well it should the retrieve the file for download and executed your php script if the you replace your php file for the query in the .js file if it fails let me know

Comment: Thanks very much Gert, Rasclatt's solution works for me so I've use their solution. I will see if this works for me too though, just in case you want to know if you're right. Thanks again appreciate the help.